# Accesing matplotlib.axes.errorbar properties from pyqt Figure options dialog

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5

I am writing an application in pyqt5, with plotting done by matplotlib, showing some experimental data (with given uncertainties) and the corresponding fit.

When I am using matplotlib with qt backend, the navigation toolbar allows changing properties of the lines that were drawn with `plot`, if they have a label. I cannot access the properties of the line produced by `errorbar`. The errorbar container has a label, but the line retrieved by `ax.get_lines()` has `'_nolegend_'` label.

The issue is somewhere here: 
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/3ca813940b0b7a7640948640fe2c9ed1ebdf27e5/lib/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py#L77

Is there a simple way to access errorbar properties?

Comment: Not sure why the vote down. A comment would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no easy way to manipulate the properties window from the outside, apart from monkey patching the linked function.